# Cleaning up duplicating Python Add-in buttons in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I have developed an extensive toolbar with ~30 buttons, tools, combo boxes, etc created using the Python Add-in Wizard and ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Something about my development process is causing the buttons, tools and combo boxes to duplicate on my toolbar. Some are now appearing up to six times every time I reload the add-in. I can use customize to remove the duplicated buttons, but even simply re-opening the mxd causes the duplication to reoccur.

Generally, the associated files are located on a network share and I copy the .esriaddin to a different network location to distribute to a number of users. I sometimes copy these files to my local drive, edit them offline and install the add-in to test offline.

If I go to Add-in Manager, I only see my add-in project once. I have tried deleting it and reinstalling it.

The config.xml file only associates each button to a menu or toolbar once.

The users that I distribute the add-in to do not see this duplication behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Normal.mxt is possibly corrupt.

Go to:

```
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates
```

and delete the Normal.mxt file.

This will remove all toolbars/customization from ArcMap.

Here's a little more [information](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00v000000005000000) from ESRI.

Comment: @XIY Awesome! ..