# ArcGIS Toolbox functions missing all parameters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.3, installation

I recently installed ArcGIS 10.3.1 and now all the toolbox functions (that I have tried) open, but they have no parameter fields. For example, the "Add Field" tool comes up with the standard toolox dialog with the title bar, buttons at the bottom, and a functional help panel, but the rest of the dialog is entirely empty.

I've run a repair on the installation.

Has anyone else seen this? Any fixes?

Same thing after uninstalling all ArcGIS applications and reinstalling.
Other details: Windows 7, 64 bit, SP1, Intel CPU

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Please be aware that statements of urgency should not be used on your posts because all potential answerers volunteer their time and we are not a GIS support site: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/should-statements-of-urgency-be-removed-from-questions

Comment: If closing and restarting ArcMap, and possibly rebooting, does not clear this then perhaps your Normal.mxt is corrupt: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/120120  The way that I would describe this is that your tool dialog is blank - that may give you some more ways to search for anyone else who has resolved similar symptoms.

Comment: A bunch of different things can cause this. Some suggestions [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=983&t=194911) and other possible problems [here - if you have McAfee](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41057) and [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33792) and [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/10882).

Comment: I know that updates to Internet Explorer have upset Toolbox tool dialogs in the past. What version of IE are you using? Suggest you check the KB pages on the [esri support site](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles)?

Comment: IE Version 11.0.9600.17843 Update versions 11.0.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems with JavaScript in IE were the problem. The toolbox uses JavaScript to display the parameter prompts. We used whatismybrowser.com/is-javascript-enabled to determine the status of JavaScript in both IE and Chrome. It was working in Chrome, but not in IE even though it was enabled in the settings. We found that our virus software had disrupted JavaScript in some registry settings, and updates to IE had not completed properly. Reinstalling IE, then restarting the virus protection restored JavaScript and the toolbox parameters.