# ArcGIS tool when opened is not appearing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, buffer, arctoolbox, arccatalog

Recently I came across an issue with my ArcGIS tools not appearing when selected. All that appears is the tool dialogue box and it is completely blank (white).

What is causing this tool not to display?

Here is how is appears when I open the Buffer tool (I've tried this with other tools as well):

[image]

The tool does appear in ArcCatalog

[image]

I've tried rebooting ArcGIS and my computer to no avail.

I found this [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153589/arcgis-toolbox-functions-missing-all-parameters) however it hasn't solved my issue.

Comment: Were there any recent changes to your system? Other software installed?  Windows updates? What version of ArcGIS? Are the tools blank in  ArcCatalog or just ArcMap? Looks like you may need to reinstall ArcGIS.

Comment: No recent changes that I am aware of or new software changes. It's ArcGIS 10.3.1. Also, in ArcCatalog the tool shows, i 've updated my question to include the screen shot.

Comment: I've never seen that happen before.  I would try a reinstall.

Comment: I'm hoping an alternative method instead of the reinstall at the moment.However, i will keep that option open.

Comment: Agreed, it's not ideal.  Maybe a repair installation. But even that may take a while.

Comment: Yes try a Repair Installation

Comment: You may want to look at this [thread as well on geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/39397) and from that thread is a link to an [esri support page](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011764) concerning the issue.

Comment: Before repairing or reinstalling I would try deleting/renaming the Normal.mxt.

Comment: I had this issue before and it was related to internet explorer settings and how help page parses the source HTML. Please have a look at @GeoSharp's link before proceeding with reinstallation or such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried the suggestions from the comments as well as read through the threads referred too, however they didn't lead to a solution.

I was able to figure out the solution after some tinkering. It had something to do with my Internet Explorer default settings. After, I reset the settings my Buffer tool worked.

Here are the steps that worked for me:

Go to Internet Explorer settings

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then click on reset:

[image]

Clicked on reset button:

[image]

Then choose the Buffer tool in ArcGIS

[image]